# Magento soap request

Tags: xml, soap, magento, wsdl, xslt

I need some help.

I want to create a product in magento via soap.
In Version 2 of the wsdl creating a product works fine, but updating the same prodict does not work, I don't know why. 
I can send the request catalogProducInfo and I get the correct information.
Then I send the exact same product id with the request catalogProductUpdate and the answer is 'product not exist'.

So I want to try the wsdl Version 1, but I don't know how to use the webservice.

I have to use xml and xsl-transformation, no java or php.

Can anyone give me a complete xml-request for creating a product for the wsdl version 1?

Thanks a lot.
Greetings LStrike

Comment: "Hello, I wrote some code and it doesn't work, and I want you to fix it without seeing the code"

Comment: It was a general question about magento soap. I asked, if anyone has some code for me, not to correct my code.  Anyway, I have figured out my self, how to update a product with soap v2.  I have to fill the xml field 'productIdentifierType' with the value 'sku' or 'id'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this question:

> It was a general question about magento soap. I asked, if anyone has
>   some code for me, not to correct my code. Anyway, I have figured out
>   my self, how to update a product with soap v2. I have to fill the xml
>   field 'productIdentifierType' with the value 'sku' or 'id'.